# simulate addition of new record by adding 1 to field ID

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

How may i retrieve the total number of records from a table via a SQL select, store it in a variable & in turn, add '1' to it @ a textbox to simulate the addition of a new record?

I have the following:

```
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (product_category_id) FROM ProductCategory"
            Try
            myConn.Open()
            dtrReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

            If dtrReader.HasRows Then
                'search DB for total records
                Dim a As Integer = ???
                lblProductID.Text = "Entry Number " + ((a + 1).ToString)
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
```

Comment: Okay which bit are you stuck on and what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes i will do so soon. Hi Tony, ive tried the above, but the syntax is wrong & i'm sure i'm missing something very obvious. will u provide me some sample code, if i need to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is iffy, real iffy.
If it's auto inc and you can guarantee exclusivity, ie no one can insert/delete another record, while the id you are going to show is relevant then

Then select count(Product_category_id) will only work if no records are ever deleted.
Select Max(product_category_id) will only work if the last one wasn't deleted.

Given a newly created table with an Identity seeded at 1, with an increment of 1

```
1st insert will create an id 1
2nd insert will create an id 2
Next will be 3
Delete id 1 now Max is still 2 and OK but count is 1, so will be wrong
Or
Delete id 2 now Max is 1 and Count is 1 so now max and count are wrong...

Delete both and it's still wrong. Next id to use is independent of the existing data....
```

Then there's what your identity your identity_seed and increment are 1 and 1 are defaults, not guaranteed.

There might be a 'better' way, if you tell us which DBMS and version you are using SQL Server , MySQL? etc

However, the entire concept is totally flawed, the value of an auto-inc should never ever ever be shown to a user, even indirectly like this.

I wouldn't even show it after insert. It's an internal identifier within the database, don't expose it.

Why do you want to do this? There will be a better way to achieve what you need, you have to give us some clue though.

Comment: @ Tony: Alright then,will take both the advice. Rushing assignment though, not really feasible to try it. I understand where you guys are coming from, i appreciate it. :) Im using SQL server btw.

Comment: Bad habits last as long as good ones mate, and they are just as hard to break. In SQL Server 2011, you could do something like this, apparently, course that doesn't mean you should...

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you want to achieve. Some further information on that would be good. To me, it seems like, that you are trying to get the next auto incremented primary key value or row position of a transient (not yet inserted) record. If you do that, you need to consider concurrency. Since (that depends on you app of course) someone else could do the same task in a different session, the entry number displayed to this user might be "taken" by another user that has already finished the task involving the same table.

So I would first of all ask myself: Why do I need to display this value? Is this value a natural identifier that a user might write down for further tasks? If so, I would recommend to show identifiers of records only after they have been inserted (physically in DB).

Comment: you're right in saying the above. Assuming that i have no issue on concurrency, coz im doing it from an admin side, will you give me the associated guidance then?

Comment: Hi? i have been trying, any ideas?

Comment: Guidance is difficult in this case. You need to provider further information on your issue (start a new more detailed question). Like describing the user interface flow and what the page does etc... From what I can see, you should not just simulate insertion of records but insert them. It just depends on how you present app functionality to the user in this case.